# Отправка изображения в серверную часть. Spring + Js

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, запрос

Перерыл множество мест, но увы, так и не понял, в чём моя ошибка. Ситуация следующая:
Необходимо отправить изображение на сервер в специальной форме. Пользователь выбирает файл и нажимает отправить. Картинка отправляется на сервер, сохраняется в папке, а в бд прописывается путь к этой картинке.

С последним пунктом проблем нет, но есть проблема с получением на сервере самого изображения.

Реализация на Spring Boot и чистом Js.

Js

```
function updphoto() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "api/select/user/change/photo");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "image/jpg");
        var file = document.getElementById("updatePhoto");
        let formData = new FormData(file);
        xhr.send(formData);
    }
```

HTML

```
<form onsubmit="updphoto()" name="updatePhoto" id="updatePhoto">
    <div class="form-updatePhoto">
        <label for="file">Загрузите тут:</label>
        <input type="file" required class="form-control" id="file" name="file">
        <button type="submit" id="updatePhotoSubmit" >Отправить</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "change/photo", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> changePhotoByUser (MultipartFile image, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String name = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    String dir = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

    Boolean bool = some_class.photoChanger(name, image, dir);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(bool, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Собственно, проблема требующая решения - нет передачи в контроллер самого изображения из js запроса. Внятного ответа на этот вопрос я не нашёл. Я не особо хорошо знаю именно Spring, но реализация нужна.

Серверную часть проверял, она точно рабочая (написание маршрута, создания там изображения и внесение в бд).

При передаче из контроллера в сервис выкидывает ошибку:

2020-04-30 17:10:20.050 [http-nio-40001-exec-8] ERROR org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog:175 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/some_app] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: У вас `NullPointerException`, ищите ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

КЭП в комментариях ответа толкового не дал, и с такими знаниями в области чтения последней строки советовал бы идти на ответы мейл ру.

А теперь к сути решения данной проблемы:

Передать файл (как файл данным методом), увы не получилось, однако получилось передать его в виде хэша Base64. Данный метод решения написан на чистом Js и Spring без каких либо подключений.

Код на Js:

```
function updphoto() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "api/select/user/change/photo");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = (function (f) {
        return function (e) {
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"image": this.result}));
            };
    })(file);
}
```

Кусок html страницы:

```
<form onsubmit="updphoto()" name="updatePhoto">
    <input type="file" required class="form-control" id="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit" id="updatePhotoSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Такая передача позволила передать в контроллер, но сразу оговорка!

Из кода выше было видно, что использовался MultipartFile, но был изменён на строку в классе *UserChangePhotoRequest*, и имеющий поле *String image* и сеттеры и геттер к нему. Специально покажу на всякий случай:

```
public class UserChangePhotoRequest {
private String image;

public String getImage() {return image;}

public void setImage(String image) {this.image = image;}
```

}

Именно поле *image* гарантирует нам передачу из реквеста в контроллер (с этой проблемой дня 2 возился).

Конечный вариант контроллера выглядит следующим образом:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/select/user/change/photo", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> changePhotoUser (@RequestBody UserChangePhotoRequest imageBase64) {
    // получение имени пользователя из нынешней сессии
    String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    Boolean bool = some_class.photoChanger(username, imageBase64);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(bool, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

И уже в самом классе *some_class* занимаемся обработкой данной информации. Лично я решил просто добавлять в бд и не придумывать танцев с бубном.